# Inputs of a method depending on the template structure

Tags: c++, templates, static, metaprogramming

```
template <typename Stru_>
    class templateClasse{
    public:
    
      using stru = Stru_;
    
      static void method_0(int sk, int sl){
        printf("class templateClass method_0 sk: %d sl: %d\n", sk, sl);
      }
    
      static void method_1(int a){
        if (stru::isvec){
          method_0(0, a);
        } else{
          method_0(a, 0);
        }
      }
    };
```

I would like to change the inputs in the `method_0` depending on the bool `stru::isvec` as the code shows, meanwhile, I wish that the choice of `if (stru::isvec) else` branch is made during **compilation** rather than the runtime. My questions are:

1. Does this code choose the `method_0` during compilation?
2. The code is successfully compiled only when I add the keyword `static`before those two methods. Why should `static`works in this case? Usally, my understanding of `static`is like this:

> These static variables are stored on static storage area, not in
> stack.

and I know when I use `static const int tmp = 50;` this `tmp` is computed in compiled-time. So can `static` be roughly understood as a keyword to help compile-time computation?

3. Do we have other solutions in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The keyword `static` has multiple meanings depending on where you use it. Inside a class definition, it shows that a member of the class will not be associated with any of the instances of the class and will therefore have an extended lifetime. It has nothing to do with stack/heap/read-only memory section/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Does this code choose the `method_0` during compilation?

No, the dispatch happens at run-time.

You can use [constexpr if (since C++17)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) to make the dispatch performed at compile-time.

```
void method_1(int a){
  if constexpr (stru::isvec){
    method_0(0, a);
  } else{
    method_0(a, 0);
  }
}
```

> 2. The code is successfully compiled only when I add the keyword `static` before those two methods.

No, you don't have to. This is a side issue; in class definition `static` is used to declare [`static` members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) that are not bound to class instances.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AfmCqiQASndJJd9E)

With C++11, you can perform overloading with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). E.g.

```
template <typename T = Stru_>
typename std::enable_if<T::isvec>::type method_1(int a){
   method_0(0, a);
}
template <typename T = Stru_>
typename std::enable_if<!T::isvec>::type method_1(int a){
   method_0(a, 0);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mi9dNgBPqqNmceUP)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do we have other methods that work for C++ 11 to make the dispatch performed at compile-time?

Comment: @picklesmithy129 Answer revised.